# Flexslider doesn't show images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have added flexslider js and css files, also added the slider block code as the official sample had added them. In the result, i can't see the images in any browser, but in "View Source" mode, i can see the changes has made by js file and there isn't any problem in there.
When i removed the css or the js file from  images were shown properly, but when i added them again, prev, next and navigation links are added but images disapear.
What should i do?
My  codes:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flexslider.css">
</head>
```

And my code for the slider block:

```
<div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="slide1.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="slide2.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="slide3.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="slide4.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And js code to enable flexslider:

```
    $(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
```

Comment: Try to load script.js after you load jquery.flexslider-min.js

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work

Comment: I think your problem in about your custome css , if you have a custome style , check direction of your slider . you take it direction : ltr ;

Comment: This direction saved me, Thanks @saghar.fadaei